# "use" column in /proc/net/ip_conntrack or nf_conntrack?

Tags: iptables, nat, conntrack, nf-conntrack

i'd like to hack together my own little script to parse conntrack data, to get customized network information from some Linux boxes that are also NAT routers.

an example of a line from the conntrack tables is:

```
ipv4 2 tcp 6 300 ESTABLISHED src=1.1.1.2 dst=2.2.2.2 sport=2000 dport=80 src=2.2.2.2 dst=1.1.1.1 sport=80 dport=12000 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
```

all those fields have been described elsewhere, but I can't find any information on the very last column (use=2, but usually use=1).

while planning my script, it has occurred to me that the exact same IP/port combinations might in theory repeat themselves - i.e. get opened, pass some data, get closed, and after a while get opened again.

Might this "use" column indicate that this ip/port combination has already been seen before?
If so, in what timespan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`use`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.h#L60) property is a reference count. Mainly it used by the garbage collector. Instead periodic parsing of `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` file you can parse the output of `conntrack -E` command to handle conntrack events in real time.

If you interested in details, you can read the chapter 9 of "[Linux kernel networking: Implementation and Theory](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781430261964)".